# mySQL running 5x slower after optimization?

Tags: mysql

I have a Xeon 2.0Ghz server (12 cores) with 16GB memory, running Apache and mySQL for a website with around 50,000 records in InnoDB (Percona). My queries used to return in about 0.17 to 0.25 seconds, then I ran the Percona tools mySQL optimizer, uploaded the new my.cnf file and suddenly the same queries are taking 1.20 to 1.30 seconds, so about 5x longer.

What did I do wrong? Here are my old and new my.cnf files"

NEW:

```
[mysqld]
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB

key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000

log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 200
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 1024
table_open_cache               = 2048

innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 12G

log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

OLD:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12000M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 20

read_rnd_buffer_size=50M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_type=1
tmp_table_size=512M
wait_timeout=90
query_cache_limit=64M
key_buffer_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=512M
max_allowed_packet=32M
log_slow_queries
log-queries-not-using-indexes
long_query_time  = 1
```

Comment: Did you warm up the DB before trying your requests after restarting mysql with the new configs? If caches are cold, of course it can only be slower

Comment: We may need more information to answer correctly your question: your query, the schemas of all tables used in your query, the output of `EXPLAIN your_query_here`

Answer (score 0):

Are you swapping at all after running for a while?

You might try turning down your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`  since you say the server is also running Apache.  At the moment it looks like MySQL has the potential to use up all the server's memory for itself and leave nothing for the OS and Apache.

Try setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `8G` and then set `innodb_log_file_size` to `2G`.

You can probably up your `innodb_thread_concurrency` as well, but since it isn't a dedicated MySQL server it may be fine at the default of 8.  It depends on what CPU you have but the docs say:

> The correct value for this variable is dependent on environment and
>   workload. You will need to try a range of different values to
>   determine what value works for your applications. A recommended value
>   is 2 times the number of CPUs plus the number of disks.

So play around with that and see what works best.

Also, is your database larger than the amount of RAM you have or could your entire DB fit in memory?

Just keep in mind that since you are running Apache on the same server, Apache is going to want to create a bunch of its own threads and consume as much memory as required for all the server processes and if you're running something like PHP that's going to take up memory as well.

You're going to have to find a good balance where both Apache and MySQL can both perform at maximum capacity on the same system but where neither one uses so much memory that the other has to swap.

Additional ways you can troubleshoot or profile performance would be to check your slow query log and run explains on the slow queries.  In addition, you can install the Percona toolkit and run `pt-query-digest` to analyze your performance.  Read the docs [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html).